# Mobile Push SDK log - Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

how to get the below details as our developer team is unable to fetch these for investigation. Require these for IOS

SdkStatelogs, SDK Console log and Config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ask your dev team to fetch the logs by adding the code snippet for SDK version 8+

### SDK logs

SFMCSdk.setLogger(logLevel: .debug, logOutputter: LogOutputter(), filters: [.module, .identity])

### SDK State:

print("SDK State = (SFMCSdk.state())")

You may refer the following doc for more details:
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/ios-debugging.html